# AttributeError: module 'pip._internal.download' has no attribute 'HTTPAdapter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I recently upgraded my pip to 19.3. When I did that I cannot use any pip commands. OS - Mac

When I googled and researched more, most of the suggestions were to downgrade the pip package. However, even when I tried that I am getting the same result. In fact, force installs or uninstall or sudo commands nothing works.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.virtualenvs/myvenv/bin/pip", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/main.py", line 45, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/Users/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand
  File "/Users/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.operations.prepare import RequirementPreparer
  File "/Users/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip._internal.download import unpack_url
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/Users/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wrapt/importer.py", line 158, in load_module
    notify_module_loaded(module)
  File "/Users/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wrapt/decorators.py", line 443, in _synchronized
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wrapt/importer.py", line 136, in notify_module_loaded
    hook(module)
  File "/Users/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip_system_certs/wrapt_pip.py", line 8, in apply_patches
    override_ssl_handler(download)
  File "/Users/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip_system_certs/wrapt_pip.py", line 17, in override_ssl_handler
    class SslContextHttpAdapter(download.HTTPAdapter):
AttributeError: module 'pip._internal.download' has no attribute 'HTTPAdapter'
```

Can somebody help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be because you installed the [`pip-system-certs`](https://pypi.org/project/pip-system-certs/) package, which hooks into `pip` internals in a way that was never supported. This promptly broke as soon as you updated `pip` and the stuff `pip-system-certs` wanted to mess with got changed.

You will at least need to get rid of `pip-system-certs`. It looks like it was installed in a virtualenv, so you can probably just deactivate the env and make a new one... but if so, it seems like you would have already tried that. If you didn't already try that, make sure to try it next time! If you did already try that, then you probably wrecked more stuff than we can see, and you may need more drastic measures, such as a full Python reinstall.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! Had no other way other than creating new environment :(

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to go to `<your conda environment>\Lib\site-packages` and remove all occurences of `pip-system-certs`. In my case it was one file and two folders.

Answer (score -1):

`pip-tools~=4.2.0` is compatible with `pip>=19.3`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25139465)

Comment: Yes, it does. Because installing fresh pip-tools troubleshoots